# ORDER BYにDATETIMEを設定しているVIEWテーブルに対してDATETIMEのWHEREが効かなくなる

Tags: sql, mariadb

```
-- 会社テーブル
CREATE TABLE `companys` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `companys` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, '会社A'),
(2, '会社B');

-- ユーザーテーブル
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `company_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `name`, `created`, `company_id`) VALUES
(1, 'タロウ',  '2020-06-01 00:00:00',  1),
(2, 'ジロウ',  '2020-06-02 00:00:00',  2),
(3, 'サブロウ', '2020-06-03 00:00:00',  1);

-- VIEWテーブル
CREATE VIEW `users_view` AS select `u`.`id` AS `id`,`u`.`name` AS `name`,`u`.`created` AS `created`,`c`.`name` AS `company_name` from (`users` `u` join `companys` `c` on(`u`.`company_id` = `c`.`id`)) order by `u`.`created` desc;
```

上記で作成したVIEWテーブルに対して、下記SQLでレコードが取得できません。

```
SELECT * FROM `users_view` WHERE `created` >= '2020-06-02 00:00:00';
```

ただし、VIEWテーブルのORDER BYを下記の通り、DATE_FORMAT関数で指定するとレコードが取得できるようになります。

```
select `u`.`id` AS `id`,`u`.`name` AS `name`,`u`.`created` AS `created`,`c`.`name` AS `company_name` from (`users` `u` join `companys` `c` on(`u`.`company_id` = `c`.`id`)) order by date_format(`u`.`created`,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') desc;
```

これはなぜでしょうか。

---

追記

mysql --version

mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.4.12-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2

ORDERBYを指定しない場合は、DATETIMEの比較でレコードが取得できます。

Comment: 環境はMySQLですか？MariaDBですか？バージョン情報などの環境情報をいただけると幸いです。ちなみに手元のMySQLだと想定通りidの2,3だけ抽出されます。

Comment: 確認しているバージョンは下記の通りです。
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.4.12-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2

Comment: MariaDBで現象は再現できました。MySQLとMariaDBはディストリビュートの関係ですが別の製品なので、mysqlのタグは外しました。

Comment: 失礼致しました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>DBの日付のデフォルト形式がXXXX-XX-XX XX:XX:XXではないからです。</s>
<s>日付は下記のどちらかにするのが定番です。</s>
<s>・使用する際に常に形式を指定する</s>
<s>・そもそもyyyymmddhhmmssのような文字列で保存し、文字列比較でできるようにしておく</s>

6/21追記
上記回答は誤りだったため、訂正します。すいません。
mariadbのリファレンスを読む限り、上記形式自体は正当です。

原因は、以下になります。
mariadb 10.4.6では発生せず、10.4.13では発生するようです。
なお、cast(created as char)やcast(created as datetime)にするか、viewの内容の代わりにサブクエリにしても取得できます。
どこかのバージョンから、viewの挙動が変わったようです。

Comment: viewクエリのORDER BYにDATETIME型のカラムを指定するしないで、取得可不可が変わるのも上記が原因の認識で合っておりますでしょうか。

Comment: そもそもサンプルでは上はwhere文ありますが、下はないですよ

Comment: 紛らわしい書き方をしてしまい申し訳ありません。
上はVIEWテーブルに対して検索をかけたいクエリ、
下は上のクエリが通るようになるVIEWテーブルのクエリの変更例です。

Comment: mariadb 10.4.6では発生せず、10.4.13では発生することを確認しました。
cast(`created` as char)やcast(`created` as datetime)にするか、viewの内容の代わりにサブクエリにしても取得できます。どこかのバージョンから、viewの挙動が変わったようです。

Comment: バージョンによる差異があったのですね。
検証ありがとうございます。

Comment: コメントを読まなくともわかるように、本題は本文の方に記載してください。

Comment: 本題の記載を訂正しました。